# JavaScript - Is there a way to store things like "var x === var y" and "var c === var" in an array form

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm basically making some logic code for my tic tac toe game, and I'd like to write down all the states which would mean that somebody has won.

For example;

```
cell1.innerHTML = cell2.innerHTML = cell3.innerHTML //as one group
```

So when all of cell 1, 2 and 3 contain the same value, in this case X or O, it becomes true, and alerts the user. I'd like to store all the possible combinations of cells (that would be equal to end the game) in an array like configuration. I'm very sorry if I happen to annoy you with my super noob question or if no such way exists, I'm very new to programming. Thanks in advance!

P.S, I've started to learn jQuery, so if such a solution exists with jQuery, I'll be more than happy to learn it :).

Comment: You will need to compute on every change. Instead you can create combination of cell numbers that would return true on win and check that combination

Comment: Yes, an array of cells sounds like a much better idea than numbering variables `cell1`, `cell2`, `cell3`. Do that. If you have that array, you can also easily generate an array of all possible combinations dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but could you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe store the conditions as coordinates in an array. Then loop through the array to find if one of those matches.

```
var winconditions = [
  [{x: 1, y: 1}, {x:2, y:1,}, {x:3, y:1}], //top row
  ...
];

for(var i = 0; i < windconditions; i++){ //loop every condition
  var conditionMatches = true; //will stay true if every coordinate matched
  for(var y = 0; y < winconditions[i]; y++){ //loop every coordinate of a condition
    var coordinate = winconditions[i][y];
    if(!isCoordinateMarked(coordinate){ //some check if coordinate was set by a player
      conditionMatches = false;
    }
  }
  if(conditionMatches){
    //you found a match!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you,

i set an array of arrays (matrix), that contain all the possibilities for winning.

and the gameBoard will be a matrix too, of all the elements you have from the html.

```
var checkWinner = function(gameBoard) {
    const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i]; // set values from lines[i] to var a, b, c. 
  // checking if the first element no null, then check if all equils  
if (gameBoard[a] && gameBoard[a] === gameBoard[b] && gameBoard[a] === gameBoard[c]) {
      return "win";
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but JSHint shows a lot of warnings and errors with your code. Could you please go through it again, and maybe explain how it works. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: ok, i just edited '{' after the function signature.<br/><br/>

the function should get a matrix on the board game, array 3*3.<br/>
the lines array contains all the valid win variations.<br/>
then in the for loop you go thru every valid win cells in the line array,
every time you do const [a, b, c] = lines[i] -> it into a,b,c the params in lines[i] for example first time a=0 b=1 c=2, last time a=2 b=4 c=6.<br/>
the if statement check the first selected cell from the board game if not null, if null return null, if not the if checks if all the 3 selected cells are same, if true return 'win'